# MYSQL check if field contains symbol and remove

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, if-statement, replace

I've a MySql table with columns containing 3 symbols (dollar: `US$`, `£` and `?`).

[image]

I'm using PHP (in Codeigniter) to remove all of the symbols, like this:

```
$replace = $this->db->query("UPDATE wm_rendiconti_amazon 
  SET Royalty_USD = SUBSTRING(Royalty_USD, 5), 
  Royalty_GBP = SUBSTRING(Royalty_GBP, 3), 
  Royalty_EUR = SUBSTRING(Royalty_EUR, 3)");
```

This basically removes the symbols with the use of SUBSTRING.

The problem I'm trying to solve is to not cut out the numbers in case the action get run twice (which will remove again 3/5 characters).

I'd like to check with mysql "`If the field contains the symbol US$ or £ or ? then remove it`".

Is this possible with mysql query?

Comment: Why do you need to 'check' first?

Comment: @Strawberry Because if I fire the action it removes the first 3 chars, and is fine, if I fire it again it removes AGAIN the 3 chars and cuts the field content

Comment: why there is comma($6,75 etc) instead of dot like ($6.75).

Comment: @avisheks because it's imported from elsewhere...

Comment: you can use CAST function something like this:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,54553,54561

Answer (score 1):

You could better use MySQL [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function. The set function can be something like

`field_name = REPLACE(field_name, "$ ", "")` /*replace with $ with empty string */